# simple string question

Tags: c++, string

If I assign a new value too previously declared string using operator= , is it freed automatically or I have to free it manually?

```
std::string s("value_old");
s = "value_new";
```

what happens with **"value_old"**
where I can find  or  where are you always watching to find answer to similar questions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is freed automatically.

I suggest [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/) for a handy online reference to STL.

Answer (score 8):

std::string handles it's own memory, so when you use s = "value_new", the string "value_old" is sent to oblivion.

Answer (score 1):

The old value is freed and s becomes `new_value`.

From Source code [std::string](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/string), The old value is erased (from `erase()` method) and new value is `inserted` and a reference string is returned. See `assign()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Generally: If you're using `std::string` you don't need to worry. It will take care of that.

In your concrete case: Very likely your `std::string` implementation will recycle the memory it had for `"string_old"`, re-using it for `"string_new"`.

Answer (score 1):

The `std::string` manages the actual data and is responsible for memory management.

**Where I can find or where are you always watching to find answer to similar questions?**

For such questions, I would recommend a simple C++ book. A list is available on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), but I think "The C++ Language" (Bjarne Stroustrup) would be a good choice to start with.